# Adding a font for Windows Phone Applications

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, fonts, truetype

I'm trying to change my font to a custom tff file. I have followed [this tutorial](http://blog.markarteaga.com/CustomFontsInWindowsPhone7Application.aspx), but it doesn't seem to be working. I followed its exact steps and nothing. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367091/xcode-custom-ttf-font-not-working

Comment: Seems kinda confusing. Is it for Microsoft Visual Studios 2010 for Windows Phone o-O?

Comment: if you followed the tutorial exactly, you are now using the Buxton Sketch font. You may want to replace the values in here `FontFamily=".\Fonts\BuxtonSketch.ttf#Buxton Sketch"` with the font path and font name you are intending to use, like `FontFamily=".\Fonts\Quagmire.ttf#Giggity"` or your values.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code you are using it is hard to say what could be wrong. Take a look at [this sample](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/24/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-24-embedding-fonts/) by Jeff Blankenburg.

Answer (score 0):

As Den has said I used Jeff's sample to include custom fonts.

When I added the fonts to my app, initially it did not work. It was because I assumed the file name was the font name. Later when I opened the ttf file, the first line was the font name and it was different from the file name.

Just a clue.