# Some special Vietnamese characters wrong size when use custom font

Tags: ios, fonts, uitextview

I follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367091/xcode-custom-ttf-font-not-working) to add this [custom font](https://github.com/lequysang/gitfiles02/blob/master/VPSVYT.TTF) and it work.

```
[self.textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"VPS_Vinh_Yen_Thuong" size:26]];
```

But there are some special characters become bigger and not follow font format after typing like this:
[image]

This problem don't happen when set font of UITextView to Arial.

Please guide me what I need to do to solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: May be this font doesn't support those special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, the font I get not design using Unicode encoding.
So I must find another font and learn to redesign that font